# ip address range for Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS)

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

IOS has an IP Address ranges for APNS servers, so i can send push notification from within a protected server.

what is the ip address range for Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS)?